# Replace values in a flat array using an associative, lookup/mapping array

Tags: php, arrays, replace, mapping, lookup

This should be an easy one liner, but I can't quite get it:

I have an array like this:

```
$a = ["z", "x", "y"];
```

and an array like this:

```
$b = ["x"=>"a", "y"=>"b", "z"=>"c"];
```

what is a php oneliner to get:

```
$c = ["c", "a", "b"];
```

I want to use each element of a to index into b and return an array of the results
I've been looking at array_map but couldn't figure out how to bind b to the callback function.

Comment: If there is any, it [is on this list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Comment: @Mołot, thanks this is the list I was looking at.  It seems like array_map is the "correct" choice here, but I don't know how to bind $b as a parameter to the callback?  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You're missing `return` in your function. And `use($b)` does the binding

Comment: @onetrickpony, thanks I found that in the manual.  This is the part I was missing.  If you update your answer, or post another, with the array_map version, I will accept it.  I am testing this now.

Comment: @onetrickpony, I tested the array_map version and this accomplishes what I want.  I'd also entertain any opinions on the array_map version versus the version you originally posted.  I'm not good enough yet with PHP to be aware of any corner cases that wouldn't be covered with the array_map version.

Comment: Just use the one you find easier to understand

Comment: @onetrickpony, will do thanks for your help.  I'd like to give you credit for the solution.  If you post the answer, I will accept it.  If you don't care about the rep (you have quite a lot), then I will post the answer and accept for future newbies like me :-)

Comment: Go ahead, I don't mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up with with help from @onetrickpony:

```
$a = array("z", "x", "y");
$b = array("x"=>"a", "y"=>"b", "z"=>"c");

$c = array_map(function($key) use ($b){ return $b[$key]; }, $a);
```

The key to this is the 'use' keyword to bind to the associative array to the closure.
Pretty simple once you know what you are looking for :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$c = array();
foreach ($a as $key => $value)
{
    if (isset($b[$value]))
    {
       $c[] = $b[$value];
    }
}
```

Comment: @TFinnis, I was going down this road but figured there was a more "functional" way to do this.  I will probably choose onetrickpony as the answer, but I gave you a +1 for the working solution.

Comment: This code is wrong.  I suggested this as an edit, but it seems to have been rejected.  $a is not an associative array, so $key will be set to the positional indices: [0, 1, 2].  To correct the code, lose ` => $value` in the foreach line.

Comment: @joeshmo, after looking again, you are correct.  My intent is that $a is not used as an associative array.  I think your fix is right for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

```
$c = array_merge(array_intersect_key(array_flip($a), $b), $b);
$c = array_values($c);
```

Not really a one-liner, but close :P

Comment: It can be written as a one-liner though.

Comment: `array_merge(..., $b)` adds everything from $b, so this solution is probably incorrect. `array_values(array_intersect_key($b, array_flip($a)))` is better but order of resulting elements is different.

Answer (score 1):

With modern PHP, you can use arrow function syntax to access the second array without `use()`. As you iterate all of the values in the first array, check the mapping/second array for a matching key.  If a match is found, use that; otherwise use the null coalescing operator to fallback to the original value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/k2A6v))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($v) => $b[$v] ?? $v,
        $a
    )
);
```

With the asker's original arrays, all elements are mapped, so the null coalescing is not necessary -- this is just a way to cover similar questions with missing keys in the lookup array.

If the lookup array might contain `null` values, then you'll need to use `key_exists()` [like this](https://3v4l.org/eTp8J).